# IdentityServer: How to create databases for EF support & aspnet Identity support

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

So based on IdentityServer3 documentation I can use Entity Framework to store clients, scope and operational data ([documentation here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/ef/overview.html))
I need to install nugget package using `Install-Package IdentityServer3.EntityFramework`
However I couldn't find any instruction on how to create database. What command or script I need to run in order to create underneath database

Same kind of question applies for User Store. I am planning to use Asp.Net identity to store user information. and I need to install `Install-Package IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity` package. No clear instruction on creating database structure

There are corresponding sample project [EntityFramework](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/EntityFramework) and [AspnetIdentity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity) but can trust if these projects are using latest schema.
Also sample projects creates database with sample data. I want the clean database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs clearly say that you are in charge of the DB schema and migrations: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/ef/migrations.html

Comment: You right in terms of migration, however to do migration I need to build an Initial Model & Database first. (and also I'm not looking for migration either) I am looking for How to build an Initial Model & Database for Clients, Scopes and ASPNET identity without any data.

Comment: There will be schema changes, so you will have to have some sort of approach to dealing with that. If you use EF then you can use migrations. If you use our EF library, then you have a set of entities that are a snapshot of the schema at a point in time. You're still expected to manage migrating those over time.

Comment: As I said migration will be come afterword once we finalize on IdentityServer. Currently I am reviewing IdentityServer to see if its going to fit our requirements. To do that I'm developing proof of concepts.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion here is that you use the same EF migration tools to also create the DB. Again, see the `Update-Database` in the docs link above.

Answer (score 1):

Question is about the initial set up and not when the IdSrvr will be enhanced.

Add nuget for identityServer3.EntityFramework (choose your version.). In your DbContext Class add:

```
public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
public DbSet<ClientClaim> ClientClaims { get; set; }
public DbSet<ClientSecret> ClientSecrets { get; set; }
public DbSet<Consent> Consents { get; set; }
public DbSet<Scope> Scopes { get; set; }
public DbSet<ScopeClaim> ScopeClaims { get; set; }
```

Run the add migration command in console and you'll see the initial migration.